# How to retrive information like PID, PPID, Depth in bash of all processes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, gnome-shell

I will trigger seven dummy descendant processes using below code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
    set -- 7 #To set command line argument to 7 when arguments aren't provided
fi

if [[ "$1" -gt 2 ]]; then
    "$0" "$(($1 - 1))" #Execute same script by passing a number(decrementing)
else
    sleep 120
fi
```

Thus `pstree -pc 101` (assuming 101 is pid of first process of above script) will display:

`dummy(101)──dummy(102)──dummy(103)──dummy(104)──dummy(105)──dummy(106)──sleep(107)`

How do I display the information of the dummy process in below format:

| PID | PPID | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | 106 | 1 (indicates child) |
| 106 | 105 | 2 (indicates parent) |
| 105 | 104 | 3 (indicates grand parent) |
| 104 | 103 | 4 |
| 103 | 102 | 5 |
| 102 | 101 | 6 |
| 101 | 100 | 7 |

Frankly I do not know Bash scripting. I have just learned how to to display PID'S of a user processes using below command:

`ps -u $USER -o user,pid,ppid,lstart,cmd`

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get required information using recursion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_child()
{
  local -i pid=0 ppid=$1 depth=$2 parentId=$3
  echo $ppid $parentId $depth

  while read -r pid; do
    echo $ppid
    ((pid)) && get_child $pid $((depth + 1)) $ppid
  done < <(ps -o pid= --ppid $ppid)
}

get_child $1 0 0
```