# How to list process with their depth?

Tags: bash, text-processing, process

I have a slightly different process tree question. I need to list the process and their depth in scalar value. `pstree` gives the result in a "graphic" manner.

```
root      100930  0.0  0.3 839396 49020 ?        Ssl  Aug15  38:20 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root      847414  0.0  0.0  76640  7788 ?        Ss   Aug24   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D 
root     2471773  0.0  0.0 161028 11436 ?        Ss   16:26   0:00  \_ sshd: root [priv]
root     2471790  0.0  0.0 161028  6492 ?        S    16:26   0:00      \_ sshd: root@pts/0
root     2471791  0.0  0.0  17064  5744 pts/0    Ss   16:26   0:00          \_ -bash
root     2483408  0.0  0.0  48064  4260 pts/0    R+   19:13   0:00              \_ ps auxf
```

However would be better to list in table and be able to filter process with depth > 3, 4, 5, etc.

| PID | PARENT PID | DEPTH | PROCESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100930 |  | 1 | rsyslogd |
| 847414 |  | 1 | sshd |
| 2471773 | 847414 | 2 | sshd |
| 2471790 | 2471773 | 3 | sshd |
| 2471791 | 2471790 | 4 | bash |
| 2483408 | 2471791 | 5 | ps auxf |

Any ideas?

PS: These question are similar but not exactly what I mean.
[How to retrive information like PID, PPID, Depth in bash of all processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691087/how-to-retrive-information-like-pid-ppid-depth-in-bash-of-all-processes)
[How many deep shells I am?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373704/how-many-shells-deep-i-am)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my OpenBSD system (also tested on Ubuntu):

```bash
$ ps -o pid=,ppid=,command= -ax | awk '{ parent[$1] = $2; cmd[$1] = $3 } function depth(p) { if (p == "" || p == 1) return 1; else return depth(parent[p]) + 1 } END { for (p in parent) print p, parent[p], depth(p), cmd[p] }' | mlr --n2p --barred label PID,PPID,Depth,Command then sort -n Depth,PID
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+                                                                                                               01:51:28 [30/1957]
| PID   | PPID  | Depth | Command                   |
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| 1     | 0     | 1     | /sbin/init                |
| 5555  | 1     | 2     | /usr/sbin/smtpd           |
| 8624  | 1     | 2     | /usr/local/sbin/obsdfreqd |
| 11258 | 1     | 2     | ssh:                      |
...
| 25177 | 78190 | 4     | tmux:                     |
| 39399 | 42657 | 4     | zsh                       |
| 61862 | 42657 | 4     | awk                       |
| 90021 | 65371 | 4     | /usr/local/bin/syncthing  |
+-------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
```

The command pipeline, pretty-printed:

```bash
ps -o pid=,ppid=,command= -ax |
awk '
{
    parent[$1] = $2
    cmd[$1] = $3
}
function depth(p) {
    if (p == "" || p == 1)
        return 1
    else
        return depth(parent[p]) + 1
}
END {
    for (p in parent)
        print p, parent[p], depth(p), cmd[p]
}' |
mlr --n2p --barred \
    label PID,PPID,Depth,Command then \
    sort -n Depth,PID
```

The `ps` command provides the raw input data and does so by outputting the PID, PPID, and the command string of every process on the system.

This is read by `awk` and we store the parent for each PID in the `parent` array, and the first word of the command in the `cmd` array.  These arrays are keyed on the PID.

The `awk` code then outputs the PID, PPID, depth, and the first word of the command string for each PID.  The depth is calculated by the recursive function `depth`, which traces the PID back to the process with PID 1 (or with no parent; this occurred on a system with lots of various containers running on it), and then propagates the accumulation of depth back to the caller.

The `mlr` command at the end is purely for formatting and sorting the output.  It uses Miller to read the space-delimited data, label it, sort it on the depth and PID fields, and then produce a pretty-printed tabular output.  That `mlr` command could probably be replaced with

```bash
sort -k 3,3n -k 1,1n | column -t
```

As for filtering on the depth, this would be trivial with Miller as you could just add another processing step with `then` followed by e.g. `filter '$Depth > 3'`.

You could also filter with `awk` if you don't want to use Miller. Piping the output of `column -t` through `awk '$3 > 3'` would extract all lines with a depth greater than three.  You could also make the `print` statement of the larger `awk` code conditional on the depth:

```c
END {
    for (p in parent)
        if ((d = depth(p)) > 3)
            print p, parent[p], d, cmd[p]
}
```